# How to add parameter to QuickSight dataset

Tags: function, reporting-services, parameters, amazon-quicksight

I'm very new to QuickSight.
trying to move **SSRS reports** to **Quicksight**.the reports contains **parameter** which I'm creating *SQLServer function* and call it in quickSight with a *sample parameter*. 
(Or use Custom SQL with the parameter value). but anytime I need to have report , I should change the parameter's value and refresh the report.

> Question : *Is it possible to have a parameterized custom SQL? or
>   function?*

I tried to use filter , but I was not successful. 
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add parameters in quicksight.

1. click parameters tab and press create one.
2. give parameter name, datatype, values.
3. you can also set a dynamic default by clicking it. select a database name, user name column and default value column and click apply.

after creating your parameter you can connect it to Filter, control, calculated field,  custom actions.
here we can use filter.

1. click filter tab and press create one.
2. select your field name and in filter type, choose custom filter and tick mark use parameter and select the parameter which we created earlier and click apply.

if you want to add control, go to parameters and click the drop-down button of your parameter and click add control.

it will ask display name,style(text box or drop down) and click add button.